# C++ template to reference count native types

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14, reference-counting

I need to reference count an `int` (file descriptor) in C++.  I was looking through new C++11 and C++14 docs to see if there was a template for reference counting.  Does it really not exist as part of the new things added to C++ over the last few years, or did I miss it in the docs?

Note I'm not looking for people to provide their own solutions as part of this StackOverflow question!  I only want to know if there is an "official" solution I should be using.

Comment: Are you looking for a variation of `shared_ptr` without the pointer-ness?

Comment: @immibis Exactly, reference counting for non-pointer types.  In my case, a file descriptor obtained through `open(3)`.

Comment: You can use `shared_ptr` with the address of the int, and a custom deleter if you don't want to dynamically allocate the int.

Comment: It'd be trivial to implement your own counter class anyway (either as base class or member of same struct containing the int)

Comment: @M.M No - if you don't dynamically allocate the int then it has to exceed the lifetime of all the `shared_ptr`s which could be difficult to arrange.

Comment: @immibis yes, but that's true of any reference-counting method for a non-dynamic variable

Comment: @M.M The question asker wants to reference-count a **value**.

Comment: They said reference count an `int`  ; no mention was made of what storage class (if any) they wanted. For example perhaps the int is a global variable and they want to trigger a function when its count returns to 0.

Comment: @M.M. Makes no sense, you need to allocate the counter anyway.

Comment: @n.m. Yes, but you could have one allocation instead of two if the counter and the managed int are in the same object

Comment: @M.M. why not just use std::make_shared?

Comment: @n.m. that's an option. Not sure what the point of this argument is.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If using shared_ptr is consistent with your intent (destroy the file when reference count is 0) then that would be the way to go. You can create the original shared pointer with a custom destructor, which can be a file deleter in your use case. It also has a use_count member function in the event you want to access that.

Comment: So the answer is "no, there is no perfect template solution in C++ for what I want to do."  But yes, I did end up using `shared_ptr` to implement what I needed.